# How do I redirect to same domain, from old blog + old permalink style to new blog + new permalink style

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

Old URL:

```
4667-harmonica-chords-and-rhythm.html
```

New URL:

```
‎harmonica-chords-and-rhythm-3330.html
```

Old Directory

```
/blog
```

New Directory:

```
/category/blog
```

I tried a dynamic redirect Match, but it did not work. I am a complete noob when it comes to htaccess. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/([^-]+)-(.*)$ /category/blog/$2-$1.html
```

Comment: That is not a dynamic solution.  Perhaps I should have been more clear.  I have 587 links that need to be 'bulk' redirected.  Hence, me saying I tried a dynamic redirect match.  This is not one link, it is many that have at its base, the rule for XXX-name.html and new is name-XXX.html.